# Bottom anchor duplicates calendar control

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, calendar, anchor

When I put a bottom anchor on my calendar control, it doubles the calendar and shows two months. 
All I want is for the calendar to stay at the bottom of the panel when the form gets maximized.

Before anchor :

> [image]

After anchor  :

> [image]

(*screenshots took at runtime*) Is this normal ? 
If it is, how can I make the calendar stick to the bottom of the panel without an anchor ? because the anchor works fine with every other controls I have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying setting `yourCalendarControl.Dock`:

```
yourCalendarControl.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
yourPanel.Padding.Left = yourPanel.Padding.Right = 30;//It's up to you
//SizeChanged event handler of your form
private void form_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized){
      yourPanel.Padding.Bottom = 0;
   }
   else yourPanel.Padding.Bottom = 200;//It's up to you
}
```

Moreover, I guess you set `Anchor` to `AnchorStyles.Bottom  | AnchorStyles.Top`, try setting like this:

```
yourCalendarControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```